# Two Particles in a Harmonic Oscillator with repulsive short-range potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

Do bear with me, I am attempting to learn to write some simulations on the computer and learn some simple MD, so I defined sort of a *toy* problem.

I have two particles confined in a Harmonic Potential Well.

- They are not identical, I label their masses $m_1$ and $m_2$.
- They interact with each other such that if their relative distance between the two of them is less than a constant $d$.

  - The interaction potential I defined is
  - $V(\beta)= \frac{1}{2}A(d-\beta)^2$
  - where  $\beta =x_1-x_2$, the relative distance between the two particles.

I would like to solve for the equations of motion numerically with a computer, and I was wondering if I was setting up the equations correctly. So it would be great if I get some feedback on the flow of my logic, and if the equations I came up with made sense.

**Step 1. I define two regions**

**Region 1: $\frac{\beta}{d}>1$; No Interaction**

$U = \frac{1}{2}kx_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$

$T=\frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2 \dot x_2^2$

**Region 2: $\frac{\beta}{d}<1$; Interaction**

$U = \frac{1}{2}kx_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}A(d- (x_1 - x_2))^2 $

$T=\frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2 \dot x_2^2$

**Step 2. I write the Euler - Lagrange Equations for each region.**

**Step 3. I will solve it numerically**

- by first giving it an initial condition.
- And the program will check the relative distance between the two particles before deciding to use the appropriate Euler - Lagrange equation for that region.
- The solver will solve at that particular time step.
- After that, I will once again repeat the check for the relative distance.
- I shall do this for ***n*** steps.

Comment: Check your kinetic energy terms. Right now they read like harmonic potential terms. The other thing is, when you say "two particles in a harmonic potential well", do you mean they "interact via a harmonic potential but are otherwise unconstrained" or do you mean "two independent harmonic oscillators that in addition interact through another harmonic potential"? Your potential energy terms fit the latter case.

Comment: @udrv thanks for your comment. i forgot to type the "dot" in the kinetic energy term.

Comment: Also, I meant to have two particles confined in the same harmonic potential (so they are free to move about inside in the same region), but they will kind of like "bounce" away from each other if they get too close to each other.

Comment: Re: "two particles confined in the same harmonic potential" and "free to move about inside in the same region", not sure we mean the same thing, so I'll put it again this way. If you take away the interaction between the particles by setting A=0 and you want them to still experience a harmonic potential individually, with k≠0, then you are set. If you want them free when A=0, then set k=0 from the get-go and handle boundary collisions. Either way, the algorithm looks good to me, assuming you take care of numerical stability when you set up the solver.